# How to put dynamic weight in elasticsearch while indexing?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, logstash

I'd like to do something similar to this indexing:

```
curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/music/song/1?refresh=true' -d '{
    "name" : "Nevermind",
    "suggest" : {
        "input": [ "Nevermind", "Nirvana" ],
        "output": "Nirvana - Nevermind",
        "payload" : { "artistId" : 2321 },
        "weight" : 34
    }
}'
```

But using logstash. In fact the part that interest me the most is the weight field.

So in the filter & output part of my config file, I'd expect something similar to that:

```
filter {
    csv {
        columns => ["Name","zipcode","weight_number"]
        separator => ";"
  }
}

output {
    stdout{
        codec => "json"
    }
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "city"
        weight => %{weight_number}  //This is it

  }
}
```

I know that this has no chance to run but I hope that I make it enough understandable for you to get what I am searching for.

Comment: You can try a mapping in input config, i never try CSV but with JDBC plugin i did similar thing : "SELECT name,views as weight from movies....".